# Use ng-model to avoid $digest delay in Component Directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model, angularjs-components, angularjs-ng-change

### How to call controller's any function in directive in angularJs

I'm trying to call parent controller's function, which has not much to do with the directive, when directive's bind value has changed.

I've been looking through the Q&A in stack, but all of them are related to passing a value from directive to controller, which is not my case.

I thought my case was generally common, the scenario is that:
display complex objects in a loop, one of property of object bind on a directive. and when the property has changed, do-something with the updated complex object.

However in my code, it prints the old object value instead of updated one. My guess is that my update function is called before $digest process has completed.

any suggestions?

plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/bWGxEmJjNmiKCkRZTqOp?p=preview

here is the **Controller** code:

```
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.items = [
      {id: 1, value: 10}, {id: 2, value: 20}, {id: 3, value: 30}
  ];

  $ctrl.update = function(item){
    //trying to update item after changing
    console.log("updated item is: " + angular.toJson(item));
  };
```

Here is the **directive** code:

```
var controller = function($scope){
   var $ctrl = this;
   $ctrl.clicked = function(){
      $ctrl.value = $ctrl.value + 1;
        
      //calling the bind on-change function defined in controller
      $ctrl.onChange();
   }
};

return {
   restrict: 'E',
   scope: {
          value: '=',
          onChange: '&'
   },
   controller: controller,
   controllerAs: '$ctrl',
   bindToController: true,
   templateUrl: 'directive.html'
};
```

and Html looks like this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in mc.items">
  <my-directive value="item.value" on-change="mc.update(item)"></my-directive>
</div>
```

and directive template:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.clicked()">{{$ctrl.value}}</button>
```

Comment: Your problem is `value: '='`, which you should not use. Change it to '<'.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov how come that would solve an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the update function is called before `$digest` process has completed.

One approach is to update the value with `ng-model` and `ng-change`:

```
<my-directive ng-model="item.value" ng-change="mc.update(item)">
</my-directive>
```

JS:

```
$ctrl.value++;
$ctrl.ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue($ctrl.value);
```

With this approach, the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#) will update the value before calling [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange).

## [The Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/p8nuTk8qgq8c50c6G7Zc?p=preview)

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myController', function(){
  var $ctrl = this;
  $ctrl.items = [
      {id: 1, value: 10}, {id: 2, value: 20}, {id: 3, value: 30}
  ];

  $ctrl.update = function(item){
    //trying to update item after changing, but here it prints out old item instead of updated item.
    console.log("updated item is: " + angular.toJson(item));
  };
  
})
.directive('myDirective', function(){
    var controller = function(){
      var $ctrl = this;
      $ctrl.clicked = function(){
        $ctrl.value++;
        $ctrl.ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue($ctrl.value);
        console.log("calling clicked in directive and value is ", $ctrl.value);
      }
    };

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: {ngModelCtrl: 'ngModel'},
        scope: {
          value: '<ngModel',
        },
        controller: controller,
        controllerAs: '$ctrl',
        bindToController: true,
        template: `<button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.clicked()">
                   {{$ctrl.value}}
                   </button>`
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular@1.6/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app='myApp' ng-controller="myController as mc">
      <div ng-repeat="item in mc.items">
        id={{item.id}}
        <my-directive ng-model="item.value" ng-change="mc.update(item)">
        </my-directive>
      </div>
</body>
```

---

> I don't quite understand those two lines:
>
> 1. `require: {ngModelCtrl: 'ngModel'}`. does ngModelCtrl works as renaming 'ngModel' so that it can be used in directive's controller?
> 2. `value: '<ngModel'` . what does `'<'` do?

`require: {ngModelCtrl: 'ngModel'}` binds the `ng-model` controller API to the directive controller with the name `ngModelCtrl`.

`scope: {value: '<ngModel'}` creates a one-way binding of the `ng-model` attribute to the controller with the name `value`.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Comprehensive API Reference - require](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-)
- [AngularJS Comprehensive API Reference - scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)
- [AngularJS Developer Reference - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)
- [AngularJS Developer Reference - Intercomponent Communication](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication)
- [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference - $setViewValue](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setViewValue)

---

Using `ng-model` enables integration with the validation API of the [ngFormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController). One can create custom form components with multiple inputs.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms - Implementing custom form controls (using `ngModel`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#implementing-custom-form-controls-using-ngmodel-)
- [AngularJS ngFormController API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

Comment: Thanks. it works. I don't quite understand those two lines:
1. require: {ngModelCtrl: 'ngModel'}. does ngModelCtrl works as renaming 'ngModel' so that it can be used in directive's controller?
2.   value: '<ngModel'  . what does '<' do?

Comment: See additional explaination.

Comment: In my-directive you are very likely to have somthing like <input ng-model=...> - that means you will have two ngModelControllers for one variable. quite sad.

Comment: Using `ng-model` enables integration with the validation API of the [ngFormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController). One can create custom form components with multiple inputs. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Forms - Implementing custom form controls (using `ngModel`)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#implementing-custom-form-controls-using-ngmodel-).